# Entity Framework query to select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

table people: SSN, name
table students: SSN, school

I want to get all SSN for people who **are not** students. How do I write this with entity framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var ssnList = Context.Peoples
                     .Where( p => !Context.Students
                                          .Any(s => s.SSN == p.SSN))
                     .Select( p => p.SSN).ToList();
```